# tkinter / Python - Hiding sub menu items at run time

Tags: python, tkinter, submenu

I would like to hide some sub-menu items based on the current configuration of a product.

I use place_forget to hide buttons, combo boxes, etc... but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for sub menu addressing for the place_forget function calls.

I don't want to remove the sub menu items, I just make sure the user can't see them. I have other code that enables and disables menu items that will fail if the items aren't there.

Comment: Menus aren't really designed to be hidden. Normally they are just disabled. Can you please provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how much simpler my request can be. I want to hide menu or sub menu items. There is no example because I'm asking how to accomplish this in tklinter. I've done it a number of ways in other dev environments and it's rocket science in those. It's a property named Visibility.

Comment: Follow up: I ended up just deleting the sub menu items. I couldn't find a way to set the visibility. Deleting the items didn't cause any problems.
I used the following syntax:
        sub_menu1.delete( "Analysis" )